# Monoids where $\operatorname{Hom}(M,M) \cong M$

Tags: category-theory, monoid

What are some examples of monoids where $\operatorname{End}(M) \cong M$? Is there a nice characterization of such monoids? E.g., they will necessarily have a zero element, since $\forall x (x \mapsto 1_M)$ is a zero of $M^M$ (so no groups satisfy $G^G \cong G$).

Examples:

- $\{1\}$
- $(\mathbb{F}_2, \cdot)$

Non-examples:

- $(\mathbb N, +) \mapsto (\mathbb N, \cdot)$
- $(\mathbb F_2, +_2) \mapsto (\mathbb F_2, \cdot)$

Comment: It's not a particularly natural question to ask; there are no obvious maps in either direction to ask to be an isomorphism, so you're just asking for some arbitrary isomorphism that isn't connected to anything. (Compare with the case of groups, where there's a obvious morphism $G \to \text{Aut}(G)$ given by conjugation that one can ask to be an isomorphism. The groups with this property are precisely the groups with trivial center and outer automorphism group; this property is called being "complete" and is quite interesting. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_group.)

Comment: @EricWofsey I suppose $C$ does need to be closed (internal hom). I've amended the question to read as such.

Comment: @Justaskin_: even if $C$ is closed, this doesn't say anything about the category of monoids in $C$. Take, for example, $C = (\text{Vect}, \otimes)$; the category of monoids in $C$ is the category of algebras, which is neither closed nor enriched over $\text{Vect}$, and endomorphisms of an algebra only form a monoid. (Even the endomorphisms of the unit here don't really have anything to do with the unit as a monoid.) This is another indication that this isn't a particularly natural question to ask.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Could you elaborate on how this does not say anything about $\mathsf{Mon}(C)$? I think that the fixed points of the endomorphism functor $\operatorname{End}: \mathsf{Mon}(C) \to \mathsf{Mon}(C)$ certainly say something about $\mathsf{Mon}(C)$. (I'm assuming this is in fact a functor, I have not checked this.)

Comment: @Justaskin_: taking endomorphisms is not a functor, and it does not land in $\text{Mon}(C)$ (I just gave you a counterexample). When I said "this doesn't say anything..." I meant that assuming $C$ is closed monoidal doesn't imply the same for $\text{Mon}(C)$. In any case this is not the enrichment you want; you want $\text{Mon}(C)$ to be enriched over $C$, but that isn't guaranteed either (and again, I just gave you a counterexample).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Oh. I see what you were saying now. Indeed I should restrict to $\mathsf{Set}$.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi The map $\forall x(x \mapsto mx)$ is not a monoid morphism unless $m = 1$, because $1 \mapsto 1$ is required. So this is a map from $M$ to $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Sgrp}}(M,M)$, not $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Mon}}(M,M)$.

Comment: @Justaskin_ Yes, I'm not really sure what I was thinking... (It also generally doesn't even satisfy $(mx)(my) = mxy$ unless $m$ is idempotent)

Answer (score 8):

**Partial answer**. If $M$ is a finite monoid such that $\operatorname{End}(M) \cong M$, then either $M = \{1\}$ or $M = \{0, 1\}$ with the usual multiplication of integers.

**Proof**. Let $G$ be the group of invertible elements of $M$. Since $M$ is finite, $M - G$ is an ideal of $M$. Let $E(M)$ be the set of idempotents of $M$. For each $e \in E(M)$, let $\bar e$ be the endomorphism of $M$ defined by
$$
\bar e(x) = \begin{cases} 
1 & \text{if $x \in G$}\\
e & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $\bar e \in E(\operatorname{End}(M))$ and moreover $\bar e \bar f = \bar e$ for all $e, f \in E(M)$. Thus the map $e \to \bar e$ is an injection from $E(M)$ to $E(\operatorname{End}(M))$. Since $M$ and $\operatorname{End}(M)$ are isomorphic, this injection is a bijection. In particular, there exists an idempotent $e$ in $M$ such that $\bar e$ is the identity map on $M$. Since the range of $\bar e$ is $\{1, e\}$, this means that $M = \{1, e\}$, which gives the two possible solutions.