# Endomorphism monoid of a product

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

Given a monoid $M$ we define the endomorphism monoid $\mathrm{End}(M)$ of $M$ to be the monoid of homomorphisms $M\to M$ along with composition as the operation. My query is whether or not the endomorphism monoid preserves products in the sense that:
$$\mathrm{End}(M_1\times M_2)\cong\mathrm{End}(M_1)\times\mathrm{End}(M_2)$$
for monoids $M_1$ and $M_2$. If so, why and if not, why does it fail and are there some restrictions which we may put on $M_1$ and $M_2$ which make the statement above true?

Thank you!

EDIT:

This question was taken down, so I will edit it. My motivation for this is purely for fun: trying to classify monoids such that
$$\mathrm{End}(M)\cong M$$
and I was hoping if that if I could get some background information and facts about endomorphism monoids, I could get closer to determining how to classify such monoids.

Apologies for the poorly posed old question: I'm still new here!

Comment: You should state the EDIT part of your post as a separate question. I think I have some partial results on it, but it is not a trivial question.

Comment: There are only two finite monoids such that $M$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{End}(M)$: the trivial monoid and the two-element monoid $\{1, 0\}$ under the usual multiplication of integers. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1564535)

Answer (score 3):

Show that $\operatorname{End}(M_1\times M_2)$ contains a sub-monoid $\mathcal N,$ isomorphic to $\operatorname{End}(M_1)\times \operatorname{End}(M_2).$

But there can be more elements. For example, if $M_2=M_1=M,$ there is endomorphism on $M\times M$, $(m,n)\to(n,m)$ which is different from the ones in the $\mathcal N.$

In particular, if $M$ is finite and $|M|>1,$ then $\operatorname{End}(M\times M)$ is finite and larger than $\operatorname{End}(M)\times\operatorname{End}(M).$

A simple example is $M=(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z,+).$ Then $\operatorname{End}(M)$ has two elements, but $\operatorname{End}(M\times M)$ has sixteen elements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Are there any nontrivial monoids such that $\mathrm{End}(M_1\times M_2)\cong\mathrm{End}(M_1)\times\mathrm{End}(M_2)$, like how under certain conditions $\mathrm{Aut}(G\times H)\cong\mathrm{Aut}(G)\times\mathrm{Aut}(H)$?

Comment: I feel some confidence there are such cases, but I can’t think of any at the moment. Perhaps if $M_1$ and $M_2$ are finite simple groups of relatively prime order, then $\operatorname{End}(M_i)$ is essentially $\operatorname{Aut}(M_i)$ (with just the homomorphism $g\mapsto 1$ added.) I think then the product of the endomorphism monoid  is is the endomorphism  monoid of the product group. @Mathsfan123

Comment: For two commutative monoids $M$ and $N$, a necessary and sufficient condition for $\operatorname{End}(M) \times \operatorname{End}(N) \to \operatorname{End}(M \times N)$ to be an isomorphism is that there are no nontrivial homomorphisms $M \to N$ or $N \to M$.